# Use of usassigned local variable but the variable is assigned

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a little project in c# in forms (visual studio) and I am having a problem.

I have the following code in my forms.cs:

```
private void Dierbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = AnimalNameTextbox.Text;
    bool fleshEater = CarnivoorCheckbox.Checked;
    Animal.Sizes size;


    if (AnimalSizeBig.Checked)
    {
        size = Animal.Sizes.Big;
    }
    else if (AnimalCheckboxMedium.Checked)
    {
        size = Animal.Sizes.Medium;
    }
    else if (AnimalCheckboxSmall.Checked)
    {
        size = Animal.Sizes.Small;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Vul een grootte in!");
    }

    Animal newAnimal = new Animal(size, fleshEater, name);

    allAnimals.Add(newAnimal);
    DierListbox.Items.Add(newAnimal.Name);

}
```

And the following code in my Animal.cs class:

```
namespace Circustrein_algoritmic
{
    public class Animal
    {
       public enum Sizes
        {
            None = 0,
            Small = 1,
            Medium = 3,
            Big = 5
        }
        public Sizes Size;
        public bool Flesheater { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


        /// <param name="size">Size</param>
        /// <param name="flesheater">True of flase wanneer dier vleeseter is</param>
        /// <param name="name">Name</param>

        public Animal(Sizes size, bool flesheater, string name)
        {
            Size = size;
            Flesheater = flesheater;
            Name = name;
        }


        public string getType()
        {
            return Flesheater ? "Flesheater" : "Planteater";
        }


    }
}
```

I am getting the error "use of unassigned local variable 'size'" in this piece of code in the forms.cs

```
Animal newAnimal = new Animal(size, fleshEater, name);
```

But when I change the code to this:

```
Animal newAnimal = new Animal(Animal.Sizes.Big, fleshEater, name);
```

The error changes to the following warning: "The variable 'size' is assigned but its value is never used.

So it is assigned, but it is not at the same time????
I do not want to change the code to this:

```
Animal newAnimal = new Animal(Animal.Sizes.Big, fleshEater, name);
```

Because I don't want my size to be pinned to Big, Medium, Small or None.
I have no clue what to do.
Does anyone have any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your first code block `size` can be unassigned if the `else` block is hit. You never return from that block of code, it continues after it and thus it can be unassigned. Maybe you meant to add a `return;` statement after the message block.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The question was well-documented, is reproducible, and OP made a reasonable effort to ask the question intelligently.  Future visitors who find themselves confused between the two errors hit by the OP may find this question and answer more helpful than other questions/answers on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hit the `else` statement, no value is ever assigned to `size`; hence the compilation error.

Either intialise the variable when declaring, or assign a value in the `else` block.

Answer (score 9):

> So it is assigned, but it is not at the same time????

I understand that these compiler messages are confusing, and apologize for that.

The error messages that deal with definite assignment and the warnings which identify possibly wrong code were added piecemeal, over time, and without a solid plan to keep them consistent.

When I was on the compiler team I made several attempts to get them more consistent and more clear, but that work had mixed success to say the least. A detailed exegesis of all those attempts would take us far afield; I've written some articles and answers about those in the past; one of them that might interest you is [this three part series](https://ericlippert.com/2014/09/25/confusing-errors-for-a-confusing-feature-part-one/).

The simple explanation is that the error and the warning are using "assigned" to mean two different things.  The error message is:

```
use of unassigned local variable 'size'
```

but that's not quite right. What it should say is something like "local variable `size` is not definitely assigned a value on all possible control flows before it is read".

If you look at your code you'll see that if the final `else` is taken, then `size` is never written, but on that code path it is still *read*, and that's an error. There's no value there to read!

You then remove the *read*, and the error goes away, because *it is not an error to fail to initialize a variable that is never read*.  However, the code now looks wrong; you did *work* to *attempt* to initialize `size` and then you never made use of that work, so that's probably a mistake.  The warning:

```
The variable 'size' is assigned but its value is never used.
```

Is using "assigned" to mean "at some point in this method you assigned a value to this local variable, but then you never read from it, so why did you assign that value?"

This warning is not seen that often; the compiler usually suppresses it. Why?  Because this pattern is extremely common:

```
int dummy = Blah(); 
// Note, dummy is never read, but I want to observe it in the debugger.
```

But in your code the compiler knows that you are probably not using `size` for the purposes of debugging; *you've only assigned it constants*. There's no mystery here about what its value is; you can just read the code and know what its exact value will be on every control flow.

So that's the difference: in the error, "unassigned" means "not definitely assigned on every control flow" and in the warning, "assigned" means "assigned at least once".

> I have no clue what to do.

There are two ways to proceed.

First technique: keep the assignments the same, but avoid the code path that lacks the assignment at the time of read.  For example:

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Vul een grootte in!");
    return;
}
```

Now there is no problem; the only path on which `size` is not assigned *returns before `size` is read*.

Second technique: Add an assignment on all paths:

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Vul een grootte in!");
    size = Animal.Sizes.None;
}
```

Now there is an assignment on every path before the read.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the reason it's saying "use of unassigned variable" is that there is a path through the code that it could take (in your first code snippet), where it might not be assigned -- that happens if it hits your final if block (where you print the message).

You can fix it either by assigning size a value inside THAT part of the method too, or you could insert a "return" after the MessageBox.show, so that it would simple drop out of the method at that point without creating an "Animal" at all (and therefore not passing an uninitialized size along).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what the others have posted, I wanted to note that the error switching to "size is assigned but never used" is not quite a conflict/opposite of "use of unassigned" - if you're sitting there scratching your head and saying "make your mind up - is it assigned or not?!" then you can look to the other answers for details on the first error:

- "use of unassigned" means "there are some possible paths in your code where this variable might not be assigned a value before it's used"; you can read a lot of tech info on this by googling for "c# definite assignemnt"
- and the second error - "assigned but never used" basically means "size only ever appears on the left hand side of an =", so it's detecting that you assign a value to it, but then you don't ever actually make use of it

As you can imagine, the two aren't in conflict - it's possible to have  a situation where you use a variable that might not have a value, and if you take that use away you're only left with code paths that assign a value but don't use it